# how to take rows containing a pattern in certain column and move them to the rows than have few commonly columns in UNIX

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I have a big tab file like this:

```
rs980   INPP5B  missense        I       749     NP_001284363.1
rs980   INPP5B  reference       L       749     NP_001284363.1
rs980   INPP5B  missense        F       749     NP_001284363.1
rs980   INPP5B  missense        I       913     NP_005531.2
rs980   INPP5B  reference       L       913     NP_005531.2
rs980   INPP5B  missense        P       913     NP_005531.2
rs1921  ISG15   reference       S       83      NP_005092.1
rs1921  ISG15   missense        N       83      NP_005092.1
rs1921  ISG15   missense        T       83      NP_005092.1
rs2607  HEATR1  missense        K       2133    NP_060542.4
rs2607  HEATR1  missense        Q       2133    NP_060542.4
rs2607  HEATR1  reference       E       2133    NP_060542.4
```

and I would like take all rows with 'reference' pattern and move one column of them right after the rows without reference pattern and moreover that have the commonly strings in first, fifth and sixth columns. So the output should be:

```
rs980   INPP5B  missense        I       749     NP_001284363.1     L
rs980   INPP5B  missense        F       749     NP_001284363.1     L
rs980   INPP5B  missense        I       913     NP_005531.2        L
rs980   INPP5B  missense        P       913     NP_005531.2        L
rs1921  ISG15   missense        N       83      NP_005092.1        S
rs1921  ISG15   missense        T       83      NP_005092.1        S
rs2607  HEATR1  missense        K       2133    NP_060542.4        E
rs2607  HEATR1  missense        Q       2133    NP_060542.4        E
```

And so on... I got it by an array with awk through two files in whose I split the references from the others but is necessary do it in the same file in bash. Are there any possibility to do this in this more simple way? Thanks in advance.

Yes @Inian. I perform two files, separating references and others. In this way I do by awk the following command something like

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"} NR==FNR {h[$2] = $1; next} {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,h[$4] file_1 file_2 > output_file
```

In which join together the columns than must be commonly in both files and then I create an array by awk to relate these columns with the other column in 
references that I want to print in the output file.
In summary one file is like:

```
INPP5B  missense        I       rs980;749;NP_001284363.1
INPP5B  missense        F       rs980;913NP_005531.2
```

and the references:

```
INPP5B  reference       L       rs980;749;NP_001284363.1
```

and so on and I apply

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"} NR==FNR {h[$4] = $3; next} {print $1,$2,$3,$4,h[$4]}' file_others file_reference > output_file
```

This is a brief summary of how I get it, but I need to do in the same original file @Inian. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming "file" contains all the lines, including the references (your "big tab file")

```
awk -F '\t' -v OFS='\t' '
    {key = $1 FS $2 FS $5 FS $6} 
    NR == FNR {
        if ($3 == "reference") val[key] = $4
        next
    }
    $3 != "reference" {print $0, val[key]}
' file file
```

Here, we process the file twice, once to collect the references, and then to print the information.

Output:

```
rs980   INPP5B  missense        I       749     NP_001284363.1  L
rs980   INPP5B  missense        F       749     NP_001284363.1  L
rs980   INPP5B  missense        I       913     NP_005531.2     L
rs980   INPP5B  missense        P       913     NP_005531.2     L
rs1921  ISG15   missense        N       83      NP_005092.1     S
rs1921  ISG15   missense        T       83      NP_005092.1     S
rs2607  HEATR1  missense        K       2133    NP_060542.4     E
rs2607  HEATR1  missense        Q       2133    NP_060542.4     E
```

Comment: Thank you gleen jackman. Works correctly. If I understand, first generate a key with the columns of interest and then if $3 is equal to reference only take account fourth column of the key. Finally if third column is different to reference prints all columns and if are equals to the key columns put the letter.

Comment: The crucial bit is `NR==FNR`: `NR` is the total number of records processed so far; `FNR` is the number of records processed so far *for the current file*. NR == FNR can only be true for the first file.

Answer (score 2):

An option is to first sort the file by the 2nd and 3rd columns respectively, then you only need process once through awk. I'm not sure which would be quicker though:

```
sort -k 2,2n -k 3,3n infile | awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"} $3=="missense"{output[i++]=$0} $3=="reference"{for(line in output){print output[line],$4;delete output[line]}}'
```

Output:

```
rs1921  ISG15   missense        N       83      NP_005092.1     S
rs1921  ISG15   missense        T       83      NP_005092.1     S
rs2607  HEATR1  missense        K       2133    NP_060542.4     E
rs2607  HEATR1  missense        Q       2133    NP_060542.4     E
rs980   INPP5B  missense        F       749     NP_001284363.1  L
rs980   INPP5B  missense        I       749     NP_001284363.1  L
rs980   INPP5B  missense        I       913     NP_005531.2     L
rs980   INPP5B  missense        P       913     NP_005531.2     L
```

Comment: smart but original key order might need to be preserved!

Comment: Thanks @JNevill. It works correctly. I'd prefer the first option it is very useful too. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Awk, processes the file twice:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }              # set separators
$3=="reference" { a[$6]=$4 }       # get $4 from reference record (twice actually)
NR==FNR { next }                   
$3=="missense"{ print $0, a[$6] }  # fetch $4 using $6 and print
' file file
rs980   INPP5B  missense        I       749     NP_001284363.1  L
rs980   INPP5B  missense        F       749     NP_001284363.1  L
rs980   INPP5B  missense        I       913     NP_005531.2     L
rs980   INPP5B  missense        P       913     NP_005531.2     L
rs1921  ISG15   missense        N       83      NP_005092.1     S
rs1921  ISG15   missense        T       83      NP_005092.1     S
rs2607  HEATR1  missense        K       2133    NP_060542.4     E
rs2607  HEATR1  missense        Q       2133    NP_060542.4     E
```

Comment: I was sure I was getting a stroke 'cause I couldn't get it to work using `NR==FNR && $3=="reference" ... ` I had to call a friend to see if he understood my speech. :D

Comment: Yeah you have to be careful with `NR==FNR && other conditions` because you want to call `next` for *every* line where NR==FNR

Comment: right. `NR==FNR{ if ($3=="reference") a[$6]=$4; next }` is what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

a two step process

create a sorted file with a synthetic key and original input order

```
awk -v d='_' '{print $1 d $2 d $5 d $6 , NR ,  $0}' | sort > temp_file
```

join on the key and filter some of the redundant fields

```
join temp_file temp_file -o1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8,2.5,2.6 | 
sort -n                                 |   # sort back to original order
awk '$4=="missense" && $8=="reference"' |   # filter required records
cut -d' ' -f1,8 --complement                # get rid of seq no. and extra field
```